# Disable pre-checked checkbox alert dialog android java

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, disabled-input

```
ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
if (checkedItems != null) {
  for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++) {
    //if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
    if (checkedItems.get(i)) {
      lv.getChildAt(checkedItems.keyAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
      String item = lv.getAdapter().getItem(
        checkedItems.keyAt(i)).toString();
      Log.i("TAG", item);
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting all the pre-checked checkbox on load of alert dialog in android. Now, I want to disable the pre-checked checkbox using :

`lv.getChildAt(checkedItems.keyAt(i)).setEnabled(false);`

But it is not working any idea how to disable is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
```

It means just 'checked item'. Your code access just a value in each check boxes.
 How about access into listview and operate the access? 
I think you should access into listview directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(A);
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
                            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                                    boolean isChecked) {
                                    AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
                                    ListView v = dialog.getListView();
                                    int i = 0;
                                    for (int i = 0; i < items. length; i++) {
                                        v.setItemChecked(i, false); // true if you want to check all
                                        i++;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for someone it will be useful.

```
((CheckedTextView)lv.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(isChecked);
```